# Synonymize [google-drive-api-v3] with [google-drive-v3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Someone created a [google-drive-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api-v3) tag

[image]

There is really no need for this tag. Yes there are two versions of Google drive api currently but there are only very minor differences.  There is no need for there to be version specific tags of this api.

I do not have the permission to create a synonym on version specific tags only moderators can do that.

Would someone mind doing that for me as I have missed the questions attached to this tag as its not one of the ones I am tracking.

[google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) -> [google-drive-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api-v3)

Comment: Good to see you on here! I left twitter some time ago.

Comment: Its great to see you!  I have a lot of SO users pinging me on twitter to check their SO questions i cant leave    Thought we were not supposed to chat in comments  

Comment: I have missed you - you were the one regret I had about leaving twitter! So good to see you and clearly this is mod abuse of powers chatting in the comments! lol  We have this chat room if you ever want to chat on here. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room It's quite nice ttytt. We've worked really hard on making the place as approachable as possible and I'm just more happy than you realise to see you posting here. I'll put this post under a fellow mod's nose - who deals with most of the tag issues on the site :)

Comment: Bhargav will have a look at this tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like somebody had already retagged all the posts from [google-drive-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api-v3) to [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api). Anyway, I proactively added the synonym as requested, just in case someone creates the tag again in the future.

[google-drive-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api-v3) → [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api) (× 10499)

Comment: Yeah i retagged everything to save you some time.  There were only three questions tagged.  I was just hoping to get it dealt with before we ended up with a large number of them and you had a huge clean up job like last time.